# CSS, transform: translateX() scale() doesn't work in Chrome Windows 10

Tags: css, transform, scale, translate

It looks like it doesn't work with Chrome on Windows 10. It doesn't scale nor translate img. Do you know what might be causing the problem? Every suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-70px) scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-70px) scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-70px) scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: translateX(-70px) scale(0.5);
    transform: translateX(-70px) scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle? Its' working for me: http://codepen.io/rikato/pen/ZQqbww

Comment: The problem is, it is working for me as well. Code is simple as that: https://jsfiddle.net/of3cbxLe/ And one of my users reported that issue. In Chrome dev tools i disabled transform and -webkit-transform and it provided same effect as his Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: works for me latest version of chrome windows 10

Comment: For me too don't know whats wrong outdated chrome perhaps :P

Comment: Hey. Can you check the live version? http://sor.jaffewebsites.com.au/our-classes/ Try to hover over an image and tell me if it's transforming.